# scala : <console>:28: error: type mismatch;

Tags: list, scala, function, pattern-matching, typeerror

I'm really newby on language scala
My error met is certainly as simply as making you laught at

```
scala> sealed trait List[+A]
defined trait List

scala> case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
defined object Nil

scala> case class Cons[+A] (head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
defined class Cons

scala>

scala> def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
     | case Nil => 0
     | case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
     | }
<console>:28: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: Cons(_, _), Nil
       def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
                                       ^
sum: (ints: List[Int])Int

scala>

scala>

scala> def test(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
     | case Cons(x, Cons(2, Cons(4, _))) => x
     | case Nil => 42
     | case Cons(x, Cons(y, Cons(3, Cons(4, _)))) => x + y
     | case Cons(h, t) => h + sum(t)
     | case _ => 101
     | }
test: (ints: List[Int])Int

scala>

scala>

scala> val example3 = List(1,2,3,4,5)
example3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala>

scala>

scala> test(example3)
<console>:28: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
 required: List(in class $iw)[Int]
       test(example3)
            ^
```

I'd just like to know why type mismatch?
The output of the def function test is well --> test: (ints: List[Int])Int!
Thanks a lot for replying,

Comment: `List(1, 2, ...)` is creating an instance of the standard library `List` instead of your own defined `List` that is the problem. First, I would advise renaming it to `MyList` _(and `MyNil` & `MyCons`)_ to avoid these kind of problems in the future, second, you would need to either implement your own `MyList.appy` so you can use that syntax or create your lists as `MyCons(1, MyCons(2, MyNil))`

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Scala console. Separate inputs are not considered as part of the same file.

So things which are exclusively required to be in the same file do not really work as seperate inputs.

`sealed` keyword also specifies that all the sub-classes must be in the same file.

So, when you do,

```scala
scala> sealed trait List[+A]
trait List

scala> case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
object Nil

scala> case class Cons[+A] (head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]
class Cons
```

Because, you are extending a `sealed trait` with `Nil` and `Cons` in separate inputs, your inheritence chain actually has problems (which Scala console will not point out, but the inheritence will not work as expected).

You need to provide the "same file" code as a single input. You can use `:paste` mode for this. Once you are done with your input, press `ctrl-D` to finish input.

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A] (head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

trait List
object Nil
class Cons
```

Now, your `sealed trait` will be correctly inherited by `Nil` and `Cons`. And your `sum` method will not have any issues.

```scala
scala> def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int = ints match {
     |   case Nil => 0
     |   case Cons(x,xs) => x + sum(xs)
     | }
def sum(ints: List[Int]): Int
```

Similarly `companion` object to `class` or `case classs` are also needed to be created in same input (using `:paste` mode).

Scala console (and Scala worksheets in IntelliJ, and also Ammonite scripts) has a lot of hidden "special" things and should not be used to learn Scala.

I will advise you to learn with proper Scala sbt projects and `.scala` files.

Comment: thanks a lot for the :paste mode, il works well ! I appreciate more the mode .scala, as you adviced ;-)